# codename one build on netbeans 7.1

Tags: netbeans, lwuit, codenameone

I have been trying to build an ios app for quite some time now. I did all the certificate provisioning etc. The problem is that whenever I send the build from netbeans to CN1 build-server it tells me that "you might have ran out of builds"... Mind you, I have only done less than 10 and only 3 of them are iphone (which failed). I know there is also a subscription to this, but I am also aware that there is a free subscription which allows a couple of builds. Is there a way I can fix this build problem. (see the output below)

```
Sending build request to the server, notice that the build might take a while to complete!
C:\TrueMobile\BeCorrect_\build.xml:82: Failed to upload to server. Its possible you ran     out of builds. Please check http://www.codenameone.com/build-server.html
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS builds take up more build credits than other platforms since they take up considerably more server resources. Hosting on a Mac is required (which is REALLY expensive) and the build itself is quite long which delays concurrent builds.

You get unlimited builds for [9USD per month](http://www.codenameone.com/pricing.html) or you can wait for next month and you will get 100 build credits again (iOS takes up 20 the other platforms take up 1).

Alternatively you can get unlimited builds for free by following the instructions [here](http://www.codenameone.com/community-outreach.html).